# How to clear exisiting dropdownlist items when its content changes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, sqldatasource, html-select

ddl2 populates based on ddl1 selected value successfully.

My issue is the data that is already present in ddl2 does not clear before appending the new data so ddl2 content just continues to grow every time ddl1 is changed.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" RunAt="Server" DataSourceID="sql1" DataValueField="ID1" DataTextField="Name2" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Selected="True" Value="0"/>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" RunAt="Server" DataSourceID="sql2" DataValueField="ID2" DataTextField="Name2" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Selected="True" Value="0"/>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql1" RunAt="Server" SelectCommand="sp1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql2" RunAt="Server" SelectCommand="sp2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Type="Int32" Name="ID1" ControlID="ddl1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have tried re-databinding in code behind on selected index change and also items.clear with little success.

```
Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ddl2.Items.Clear()
    ddl2.DataSource = sql2
    ddl2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**QUESTION**

How to get items present in an asp:dropdownlist to clear before new values are populated when the dropdownlists content is dependent on another dropdownlists selected value?

*Please post any code in VB*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using `ddl.Items.Clear()` will clear the dropdownlist however you must be sure that your dropdownlist is **not** set to:

```
AppendDataBoundItems="True"
```

This option will cause the rebound data to be appended to the existing list which will **NOT** be cleared prior to binding.

**SOLUTION**

Add **`AppendDataBoundItems="False"`** to your dropdownlist.

Now when data is rebound it will automatically clear all existing data beforehand.

```
Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ddl2.DataSource = sql2
    ddl2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** *This may not be suitable in all situations as appenddatbound items can cause your dropdown to append its own data on each change of the list.*

---

**TOP TIP**

Still want a default list item adding to your dropdown but need to rebind data?

Use `AppendDataBoundItems="False"` to prevent duplication data on postback and then directly after binding your dropdownlist insert a new default list item.

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select ...", ""))
```

Comment: Although this cleared out my selected value, it also cleared out all my drop down values to make them not available again.  I tried both "True" and "False" on the AppendDataBoundItems.  I'm sure it's probably something I missed but wanted to throw this out there just in case.

Comment: @JohnWaclawski if `AppendDataBoundItems="False"` then whenever data is bound to the list it will automatically clear the list beforehand.

Answer (score 11):

You should clear out your listbbox prior to binding:

```
 Me.ddl2.Items.Clear()
  ' now set datasource and bind
```

Comment: See my edits above. I am already doing this but it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the following

```
ddlCity.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just 2 simple steps to solve your issue

First of all check AppendDataBoundItems property and make it assign false

Secondly clear all the items using property .clear()

```
{
ddl1.Items.Clear();
ddl1.datasource = sql1;
ddl1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just compiled your code  and the only thing that is missing from it is that you have to Bind your ddl2 to an empty datasource before binding it again like this:

> Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal
>   e As EventArgs)
>       //ddl2.Items.Clear()
>
> ```
> ddl2.DataSource=New List(Of String)()
> ddl2.DataSource = sql2
> ddl2.DataBind() End Sub
> ```

and it worked just fine

Comment: I really appreciate your response however I have no idea what =new List<string>() is in VB. Its a new one on me. Do you know a VB example?

Comment: see the Edit its equal to New List(Of String)() in Vb.net